# Finding the distribution function of F(X) where F is the CDF of X

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm going over some review questions, and this question has me stumped:

> Let $X$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$. Let $F$ be its distribution function, and let $Y$ be given by $Y = F(X)$. Find the distribution function of $Y$.

Would this type of distribution have a special name? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $X$'s denisity, as $X$ is exponentially distributed is $f(x) = \lambda \exp(-\lambda x)$, so its distribution function is $F(x) = 1 - \exp(-\lambda x)$. Note that $F$ is a strictly monotone function $[0,\infty) \to [0, 1)$. For $y \in [0,1)$ we have
\begin{align*}
  \def\P{\mathbf P}\P(Y < y) &= \P\bigl(F(X) < y\bigr)\\
          &= \P\bigl(X < F^{-1}(y)\bigr)\\
          &= F\bigl(F^{-1}(y)\bigr) &\text{as $F(x) = \P(X< x)$ by definition}\\
          &= y
\end{align*}
So $Y$ is uniformly $[0,1)$-distributed.

n. b.: Note, that wqe did not use the special form of $X$, only that its distribution function is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $F_X(x)=\mathbb P(X\leq x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\geq 0$. So $Y=1-e^{-\lambda X}$ and the distribution function is given by
$$
F_Y(y)=\mathbb P(1-e^{-\lambda X}\leq y),\quad 0\leq y\leq 1.
$$

Therefore $$
F_Y(y)=\mathbb P\left(X\leq -\frac{\ln(1-y)}{\lambda}\right)=y.
$$
Hence $Y$ is $U([0,1])$-distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y=F(X)$.
\begin{align}
\phi_Y(t)&=Ee^{itY}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{itF(x)}dF(x)\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}e^{itu}du\\
&=\frac{ \left(e^{i t\times 1}-e^{i t\times 0}\right)}{it(1-0)}
\end{align}
Therefore $Y\sim unif(0,1)$.